# java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin

Tags: mysql

insert some datas,the table has Joint primary key,then following error was reported:
java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin (MGR mysql)

Solve the problem.Solve the problem.

Comment: A common reason for this error is that you are using MySQL Group Replication (MGR) but you are attempting a DML query against a table that is not supported. The table must be InnoDB, and must have a primary key (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-requirements.html).